# Populating <option> depending on first <select>

Tags: php, ajax, html

Sorry for my stupid request but it's my first time working on an Ajax.

I tryed alone for two days but I cant find the right way to solve this.

I have two `<select>`. The first one is populated with a simple query and foreach cycle, when I select `name="X"` the second select `name="Y"` options should be populated with the result of another query on `ajax.php`. ($datasy).

For php mysql query I'm using Medoo library.

I used as example [this stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062648/populating-a-second-select-box-depending-of-the-first-select-box-option)

This is `maga_scarica.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/unload.js"></script>
<br>
<h1>Sarica articolo da magazzino:</h1>
<br>
<form method="POST" action="maga_scarica.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Cod.Articolo:</label>
            <select id="X" class="form-control" required name="X">
    <?php
        foreach ($datasx as $data) {
            echo "<option>".$data["codarticolo"]."</option>";
        }
    ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Lotto:</label>
            <select id="Y" class="form-control" required name="Y">
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">N. Doc:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Numero documento" required name="ndoc">
        </div>
        <div class="col-2">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Quantita Scaricata:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Es. 410" required name="qta">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Note:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="note">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-1">
            <br><br>
            <button type="submit" name="add">Carica</button>
            <input type="hidden" value="carica" name="azione" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

unload.js inside maga_scarica.php  I dont know if it is the right way.

```
$("#X").change(function(){
    var x_value=$("#X").val();
    $.ajax({
        url:'ajax.php',
        data:{brand:x_value},
        type: 'post',
            success : function(resp){
                $("#Y").html(resp);               
            },
            error : function(resp){}
    });
});
```

And then the ajax.php for the ajax request with second query for second .

```
<?php
    $codart = "$_POST["brand"]";
    $datasy = $database->select("magazzino_mov", [
            "lotto"
        ], [
            "codart" => "$codart"
        ]);
    foreach ($datasy as $data) {
        echo "<option>".$data['lotto']."</option>";
    }

?>
```

Again sorry if someone think this is a stupid request but I have nobody to ask help.

Thank you all.

Comment: Take variables out of quotes: `$codart = "$_POST["brand"]";` ... just do `$codart = $_POST["brand"];`... same with `"$codart"` as its needless quoting.

Comment: So, after that... what exactly is your question, or where are you running into troubles? You have described what you have... but didn't really point out where things are going horribly wrong. Do you have errors to give us? Do you have expected results, that are not what is actually happening? Do you have the results of what it actually is doing? If all you are asking is "is this how I do it?" then the answer is generally "Yes".

Comment: Ok I removed the quotes, my problem is that when I select the firs option <select id="X" class="form-control" required name="X"> the second select (Y) is not loading the query inside ajax.php. Nothing appears in the second <select> (Y)

Comment: :) Look at your [browser devtools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools), the console, the network tab, look for errors in either. Check the raw response from the ajax call in the network tab.

Comment: Also, in your `ajax.php` ... do you have all the needed `require` in place for your database? Your question just has a portion shown, so I just want to make sure.

Comment: Arrrggg ajax.php had no require_one you're right :( on devtools I see ReferenceError: $ is not defined but have no idea what it means , maybe I inserted the script in the wrong way?

Comment: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined ` means you are not including jquery anywhere before your javascript block.

Comment: omg so I'm so bad with javascript, jquery included, but how can I get datasy(that is inside ajax.php) array in maga_scarica.php to printout with a foreach with all options?

Comment: Eliminating the errors from your code (missing require_once, extra quotes around POST arg, missing jquery lib include)... then it should be working as you presented. Theres not much more for me to offer. That code should work as expected (granted you fixed those errors).